# Firestore Configuration - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

About [FireStore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) configuration in existing projects. [ANDROID]

I tried to include and configure it according to the support material and it did not work.

Error while adding dependencies in Gradle-App.

Dependency that is in the Firebase tutorial: **compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.0.6'**

Note: I tried to put it as 10.2.6, and also tried to update all dependencies for the same version of FireStore. Nothing worked.

I currently have versions 10.2.6 of the Firebase services.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
```

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.
```

Note:

I checked the PlayService and Repository updates. And I also checked on the dependencies in Gradle:

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
```

You don't need com.google.firebase:firebase-database if you use Firestore alone.
and you don't need to compile all google services.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But if you want to change versions easier to avoid conflict you should use gradle "ext" :

```
buildscript {
    ext.play_service_version = '11.4.2'
    ext.firebase_version = '11.4.2'
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${play_service_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${firebase_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${firebase_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebase_version}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:${firebase_version}"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

Keep in mind that play-service-version and firebase-version should be the same.

Comment: And make sure `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services` is at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Use `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'`

Cloud Firestore was introduced in [Google Play services 11.4.2](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Comment: Already tried. Does not work. Error: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6. @SaurabhThorat

Comment: @TiagoIB Update all your dependency versions to 11.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add this line in the bottom of `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about your SDK versions?
it is in the build.gradle app level

make sure its the latest:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```